# Working with Suggestions in Elasticsearch Java API

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch

I already have a Suggest object filled with two suggestions. At this point I can't find any documentation or sample code to help guide me through fetching the suggestions from the Suggest object.

Below is how i'm fetching the Suggest Object

```
val generator:DirectCandidateGenerator = candidateGenerator("name")
            .prefixLength(0)
            .minWordLength(0)
            .suggestMode("always")
            .maxEdits(2);
val phraseSuggest:PhraseSuggestionBuilder = phraseSuggestion("did_you_mean")
        .field("name")
    .addCandidateGenerator(generator)
    .text(t)
    .gramSize(3);

val search = Global.getClient().prepareSearch("businesses")
  .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
  .setQuery(customQuery)
  .setFrom(0).setSize(max)
  .addSuggestion(phraseSuggest)
  .execute()
  .actionGet();


val suggest = search.getSuggest()
println("Suggest Size: " + suggest.size())
```

The above code is in Scala. It is pretty self explainatory if you understand Java. If you know the solution in Java then I can easily translate it into Scala code so no need to try and figure out Scala if you don't know it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: What's wrong? You get 0 suggestions I guess? Have you tried doing the same using REST?

Comment: No, like I said, the suggest object has two entities in it. The question is, How do I extract the suggestions?

Comment: The `Suggest` object is `Iterable`...not sure what I'm missing here...

Comment: Trying to forget what you wrote, moderation helps. Lets move on, by two entities you mean the two levels of iterable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather ugly approach but works:

```
val options = suggest.iterator().next().iterator().next().getOptions()
options.asScala.map(x => x.getText.string).toList
```